# d3 v4 multi-series scatterplot not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having some difficulty making a d3 scatterplot update correctly from a dropdown box. I'm quite new to d3, so my understanding may be lacking. I'm using d3 v4.

A plunk is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/p8CTWWAvXWzB7TKaMahM?p=preview

The data includes different variables (called var1, var2, etc.) for two different groups (Apples and Bananas) from a common set of plots (A, B, C, etc.). The plot is intended to show the different variables (var1, var2, etc) on a common scale, for whichever group is selected.

When a different group is selected, then points should transition to the values (on the x-axis) for newly selected group (linked by the plots). But instead, the new points are added on top of the previous points, and the previous points aren't removed either.

I guess the problem may be to do with incorrectly selecting the elements to be updated, or incorrect use of a key function to ensure the data is linked to groups? Or is it due to the nested data structure and/or using

```
.each(function(d, i) {
```

to update each variable? I've looked at lots of other examples and tutorials, but I still don't know how to fix it.

This is the graph function:

```
function updateGraph(nested, selectValue) {

  // Get the selected dataset
  var filtered = nested.filter( function(d) { return d.key == selectValue; });
    g.selectAll("#datapoints")
    .data(filtered[0].values)
    .enter().append("g")
    .each(function(d, i) { // So that multiple series can be included on the same graph
        var min = d3.min(d.values, function(d) { return d.value; } );
        var max = d3.max(d.values, function(d) { return d.value; } );

    // Join new data with old elements
        var points = d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
          .data(d.values, function(d) { return (d.Plot); } );

    // Add new elements
        points.enter().append("circle")
          .attr("cy", y(d.key))
          .attr("r", 10)
          .style("opacity", 0.5)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return elevColor(d.Elevation); })
          .merge(points)
          .transition()
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return x((d.value-min)/(max-min)); });

    // Remove old elements not present in new data (doesn't do anything)
        points.exit().remove();
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a proper "enter", "update" and "exit" selections. It should be like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/VE0CtevC3XSCpeLtJmxq?p=preview Have a look at the names of the variables. Also, you don't need the `each`, you could do a nested selection. I'd say that you don't even need the `nest`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping so fast! Can you clarify why it's necessary to duplicate the code that defines the points for the "enter" and "update" selections (after `update.each(function(d, i) { `) ? Could that duplication be avoided?

Comment: Yes, it can be avoided with `merge`: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any tips for where the `.merge` statement should go, or how it should be rearranged to achieve that?

Comment: Feel free to copy my Plunker and ask this as a new question.

Comment: Sure, thanks, I've asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178618/d3-v4-merge-enter-and-update-selections-to-remove-duplicate-code