# D3 v4: Adding mean values and highlighting datapoints in a multi-series scatterplot

Tags: d3.js

I have a scatterplot with multiple variables derived from a common set of samples, which is updated based on a dropdown box selection. This is a a further evolution of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178618/d3-v4-merge-enter-and-update-selections-to-remove-duplicate-code). Datapoints for each of the variables are added to the plot from a nested dataset, like this:

```
var filtered = nested.filter( function(d) { return d.key == selectValue; });
var update = g.selectAll(".datapoints")
    .data(filtered[0].values);
var enter = update.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "datapoints")
    .merge(update)
    .each(function(d, i) {
        var points = d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
            .data(d.values, function(d) { return (d.Plot); });
         points.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("cy", y(d.key))
            .attr("r", 10) ...
```

I want to add a mean datapoint for each variable to the plot. The mean value for each variable can easily be obtained like this:

```
var mean = d3.mean(d.values, function(d) { return d.value; });
```

But I'm unsure how to add the mean datapoints to the chart. I have tried inserting or appending the mean datapoints to the `points` entry selection, which works when the chart loads the first time but not subsequently. I also tried defining a new entry selection just for the mean data point, which doesn't work at all, for reasons that aren't clear to me. What is the best way to do this?

The data points are colour-coded by sample, so that they can be visually matched up between the different variables. I would like to make this more obvious by using a mouseover function that highlights or links with a line all occurrences of the same sample in the different variables. Currently, the mouseover function highlights only the particular datapoint that is hovered over, like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this) // and all other occurrences of the same sample?
    .transition
    .attr("r", 15)
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select(this) // and all other occurrences of the same sample?
    .transition
    .attr("r", 10)
})
```

How can all occurrences of the same sample be highlighted or linked based on the mouseover function? Is this possible using `.each`, as above, or would it require a different way of organising and plotting the data, such as a nested selection?

The full example is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GHcMsbGa7SVvbrF4gVDw?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can add listener to the mean node.

2) From mean node catch its parent group.

3) From parent node select all circles or all circles having class `points`

4) Apply transition to the selection.

As shown below:

```
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this.parentNode) //will select parent group
          .selectAll(".points")//will select all circle classed as points
          .transition()//perform transition on them
          .attr("r", 20)
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this.parentNode).selectAll(".points")
          .transition()
          .attr("r", 10)
      });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvzWPCmjOcwz6o6xBojk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't quite what I'm after. This results in all data points for the same variable being highlighted when the mouse is over the mean data point. Instead, I want all data points for the same sample in different variables when the mouse if over that sample in any of the vars. For example, the green data points in var2 and var3 would be highlighted when the mouse is over the green data point in var1. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do it. A slight modification of the suggestion above was required. I had to select the parent node of the parent node, then all circles with the same id as the current point, like this: `d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).selectAll("#" + d.Plot)`